# Confirmation of why cross-origin problems occur when using signInWithRedirect are resolved

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I know that the `signInWithRedirect()` flow in Firebase does not behave correctly in some browsers because it uses cross-origin.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6716

When using `signInWithRedirect()`, the following article is a best practice.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices

I have an app created in Next.js with authentication using `signInWithRedirect()` and deployed it to Vercel.
If I do nothing, it will not work in Safari as described in the above issue.

So I took the following 3 actions and confirmed that it works correctly.

- Reverse proxy settings(next.config.js)

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/__/auth/:path*',
        destination: `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN}/__/auth/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

- Changed authDomain when initializing FirebaseApp to the app's domain
- In GCP, change approved redirect URI to `https://<the-domain-that-serves-my-app>/__/auth/handler`.

These are the third method in [Best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices).

I do not fully understand why this setup solves the problem, and I would like to correct my understanding.
My understanding is as follows

authDomain = a.com (domain of the app)

- An authentication request is generated from the browser and redirected to authDomain (a.com)
- The request is forwarded to `https://<project>.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/` because a reverse proxy is set up
- Host the login helper code to the identity provider at `<project>.firebaseapp.com`.
- Return to a.com
- Access login helper storage from browser
- Authenticated redirect URI is set to the app domain, so the information is stored in the browser's storage in the app domain. And since the authDomain is the same as the app's, the authentication iFrame is referenced to it.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Hello, thanks for sharing this. I have the same problem and understood the same thing. In the point "In GCP, change approved redirect URI to https://<the-domain-that-serves-my-app>/__/auth/handler.", you add Identify Platform? 
Because I can't see where do to that in Firebase Authentication